# How to fix transition in IE

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, css

I have this code that contains simple transition effect that doesn't work in IE11; I've tried using content editor web part and edit source.

1.**!DOCTYPE html , head and body**(*requirement for IE*)

2.**prefixes**(*support to make animation work in IE*)

3.**meta name**(*that support animation for IE*)

The question is how to make animation transition work in IE11

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
<style>
h1{
 color:#fff;
background:#000;
border:1px solid #000;
display:inline-block;
padding:5px 25px;
cursor:pointer;
border-radius:2px;
transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
-moz- transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
-webkit- transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
-o- transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
h1:hover{
 color:#000;
 background:#fff;
 border:1px solid #000;
  }
 </style>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Button</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It is working for me on IE. Are you saying that it is working for you in other browsers and not working in IE?